# Does anyone have bst file or biblatex files for CiteThemRight Harvard style

Tags: biblatex, natbib, harvard-style, custom

I'm currently working on my MSc project report and facing a bit of a challenge with LaTeX. My university requires all citations and references to be in the Harvard style as specified by CiteThemRight Online. As a newcomer to LaTeX, I'm finding it quite challenging to create a custom BST file that meets these specific requirements. I couldn't find a custom config for natbib or biblatex for the mentioned style.